# entity manager merge(), then refresh

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, merge, entitymanager

I have a hard time using the entity manager and the merge function.

I have a MySQL database that contains an user table, which has a trigger. When you update (or insert) an user, the trigger creates a random salt, then SHA1 the password + salt.

The problem happens when I want to update an user. In my servlet, I call my SessionBean method `updateUser(User u)`, which only contains a `return em.merge(u)`.

When I debug, I look at the new password, and it is not SHA1'ed, it appears clearly (but it is modified though). Ine the database, the password is SHA1'ed and the salt is generated, but not in the application.

My question is, what do I have to do to refresh my user and set his password to the new one ? 
The only solution I've found is to restart the application, but it's not convenient at all and I can't deploy a solution that needs to be restarted ...

**PS :** I've tried the flush(), I can't do Transactional, I am using NetBeans (auto-generated classes and SessionBeans), and I'm learning Java EE, so I don't have that much knowledge. Also I tried to get the user from the database once he got modified, but the password is still in clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `entityManager` has function [refresh](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh%28java.lang.Object%29) that can refresh your entity state to state form DB. Moreover, you can configure the catch mode in your persistence.xml file : [specifying the Cache Mode Settings to Improve Performance](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjjj.html) to the one that suits you.

Comment: I have tried the refresh and it tells me an error `Can not refresh not managed object: Classes.Utilisateur[ idUtilisateur=4 ]`. I've found that this is caused by using several entity managers, but I only use one.

Comment: You may use only one CLASS on of EntityManager, but a different INSTANCE of this class. EntityManager  instance that refresh the entity shoud be the one that loaded it from DB.

Comment: The thing is that I only use only one instance of the entity manager. My code is `em.merge(u);` directly followed by `em.refresh(u);` and I don't know why it doesn't want to work (EJBException)

Comment: Does this EnitytManager also laods your entity from DB? How do you instaniate your EntityManager? Do you inject it by @PersistenceContext ?

Comment: Yes this entity loads my user from the Database (using a named query), it is instanciated by `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "PortailPU")
    private EntityManager em;` in the SessionBean, I instanciate this SessionBean only once and call a single function that only contains `em.merge(u); em.refresh(u);` (u is the object parameter)

Comment: As far as I know, default scope of EntityManger is transactionl-scope. You can extend the scope by adding 'type' parameter to your annotation: @PersistenceContext(unitName = "PortailPU", type=javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED). Maybe this could help. You can read about it here: http://piotrnowicki.com/2012/11/types-of-entitymanagers-application-managed-entitymanager/

Comment: I tried it and it didn't help, my database becomes unreachable. I think I am goign to disallow people to change their passwords "for security reasons" ahah